# Opciones select en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quisiera saber como puedo ingresar manualmente las opciones de un select, he estado usando lo siguiente:

`<%= f.collection_select :establecimiento_id, Establecimiento.order(:nombre), :id, :nombre, include_blank: true %>`

pero eso sirve para seleccionar datos de una tabla, yo quiero crear uno con los meses, será necesario crear una tabla con los meses o hay una forma de ingresar en el codigo lo que quiero?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un arreglo con los meses del año :

```
@months = ["january", "february", "march", ... ]
```

y usar el builder `f.select` de la siguiente manera :

```
<%= f.select :month, options_for_select(@months.each_with_index.map { |m, i| [m, i] }) %>
```

Esto generaría algo como

```
...
<option value="0">january</option>
<option value="1">february</option>
...
```

o Si esperas un valor en particular para cada mes podrias partir de un Hash

```
@months = {"jan": "Enero", "feb": "Febrero" ... }
```

y el builder seria :

```
<%= f.select :month, options_for_select(@months.map { |k, v| [v, k] }) %>
```